# How to increase queries per minute of Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: sql, cloud, google-cloud-sql

As in the question, I want to increase number of queries per second on GCS. Currently, my application is on my local machine, when it runs, it repeatedly sends queries to and receives data back from the GCS server. More specifically, my location is in Vietnam, and the server (free tier though) is in Singapore. The maximum QPS I can get is ~80, which is unacceptable. I know I can get better QPS by putting my application on the cloud, same location with the SQL server, but that alone requires a lot of configuration and works. Are there any solutions for this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: According to GCS documentation there is no limit on queries per minute, however there is a limit on number of connections. Please check if each queries is using a new connection.

Comment: 'What do you mean by "check if each queries is using a new connection". The entire project consists of some several small projects, one of them is for SQL. It uses JPA and C3P0 connection pool, if these information is not relevant to you, then I think you mean checking the cloud SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

- colocating your application front-end layer with the data persistence layer should be your priority: deploy your code to the cloud as well
- use persistent connections/[connection pooling](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#connections) to cut on connection establishment overhead
- free tier instances for Cloud SQL [do not exist](https://cloud.google.com/free/). What are you referring to here? f1-micro GCE instances are not free in Singapore region either.
- depending on the complexity of your queries, read/write pattern, size of your dataset, etc. performance of your DB could be I/O bound. Ensuring your instance is provisioned with SSD storage and/or increasing the data disk size can help lifting IOPS limits, further improving DB performance.

Side note: don't confuse commonly used abbreviation GCS (Google Cloud Storage) with Google Cloud SQL.

Comment: My project consists of multiple smaller projects, 1 for SQL, 1 for MongoDB, 1 is a Spring Boot, and 1 for running algorithms (in parallel). Deploy code to the cloud is the final step, I already upload the SQL database to Google Cloud SQL, MongoDB to Mongo Atlas. What you said surprises me as I think I'm using GCS for free (here as in the title I refer GCS as Google Cloud SQL so the next following abbreviations should mean the same). Just give you an example, running locally on a data set of 40k rows takes 5-6 seconds, and now it takes > 20 minutes.

Comment: I'm new to cloud stuff, from Google Cloud Console, every day I see the 300$ free tier being reduced, now it's ~290$. Does this mean I'm being charged already?

Comment: Putting the Spring Boot onto the cloud, and chose the server location the same with the Google Cloud SQL server should increase performance, right? But I don't know how much? x5, x10. I know it depends on the spec of the server and the query, just so you know that the most complicated query is just select with some criteria.

Comment: You're currently using Free Trial credit ($300), your payment method is going to be charged as soon as you're running out of it. Placing your app frontend closer to the DB is going to decrease latency dramatically. It is heavily dependent on your specific workload, how much improvement you'll see. Experiment with increasing DB instance tier, growing data disk up to 800GB SSD, employ connection pooling.